# system command bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep, system

I want to use the system command in a bash shell script. Being more specific,
if some condition  in awk is satisfied (number of working nodes is 17) I want 
to send me an email, I wrote the following code:

```
showq | grep nodes | awk '{if ($3 == 17) system("mailx -s 'Everything is Ok' armando@nodes.com <<EOF Tranquiquis EOF")  ; else  print "some nodes are not working"; fi }'
```

if I typed that I get the message:

awk: {if ($3 == 17) system("mailx -s Everything
awk:                       ^ unterminated string

The problem I think is related to how the body of the message is specified. I don't 
know how to do it. I have tried several ways to fix the error but no success.

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it had nothing to do with single quotes. Actually, I was using commands like 'showq' but one must use the whole
path of the command in this way: '/opt/moab/bin/showq' in crontabs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As 2 other answers have stated, the problem is your use of single quotes.  Unfortunately, the recommended solution they give (backslash escaping the single quote) does not work.  You cannot get a single quote by escaping it within a single quoted string.  The easiest solution for you is to write:

```
system("mailx -s \"Everything is Ok\" ...
```

Comment: I type as you suggested: system("mailx -s \"Everything is Ok\" armando@nodes.com <<EOF Message ... EOF") and I got the error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"mailx -s \"Everything is Ok\" armando@nodes.com <<EOF Message ... EOF"'

Comment: It is more trouble than it is worth to try to get a HEREDOC (<<EOF) working in this context.  Try system( "echo Tranquiquis | mailx -s \"...\"")

Answer (score 0):

you are using single quotes for awk command, and inside them, single quotes for the text you should escape them with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

```
showq | grep nodes | awk '
{
  if ($3 == 17)
    system("mailx -s \47Everything is Ok\47 armando@nodes.com <<eof" RS \
    "Tranquiquis" RS "eof")
  else print "some nodes are not working"
}
'
```

1. Use octal escapes instead of single quotes
2. You need newlines inside of that heredoc
3. "fi" is not valid for Awk